# Correct usage of SqlMembershipProvider Profiles

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, sqlmembershipprovider

I am successfully reading and writing custom profile data for my users. However due to the way this profile data is stored in the database it is very difficult to bring back queries with any of these profile values.

For example one of my profile values is "FullName". So I would like to be able to bring back a list of objects created today, along with the "FullName" of the user that created them. Before using the SqlMembershipProvider I could join onto my User table and bring back the FullName property. Instead now I would bring back the joined aspnet_Profile and perform some string manipulation with the PropertyNames and PropertyValuesString properties.

Is what I'm attempting to do correct or am I solving this problem in the wrong way? Should I even be using the SqlMembershipProvider?

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am using .NET 4 and MVC 2.